# Rewrite a URL using preg_replace function

Tags: php, regex

I have a url say like http://www.something.com/folder_path/contacts.php/ ( starting with http:// and ending with .php/ ). Please make sure about the slash(/) at the end of the URL.
Now I want to rewrite the URL by replacing the last element of URL i.e. /contacts.php/ to /index.php/ by matching it using regular expression.

Example code -

```
$url = "http://www.something.com/folder_path/contacts.php/";
$new_element = "index.php";

$regex = "#[^/.*](\.....?)/$#"; // what would be the regular expression 

$new = preg_replace($regex,$new_element, $url);
```

The result would be http://www.something.com/folder_path/index.php/

also the path could be longer..all I need to replace is the last part of the URL.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex: `$regex = "#[^/.*](\.....?)/$#";` is not matching `contact.php`.
You should use:

```
$regex = "#[^\/]+\.php\/?$#";
```

This is matching any character except `/` + `.php` + `/` (optional) + END Of STRING

Comment: Yeah..thanks a lot..it worked. :D Can you explain me the Regular expression before .php please?

Comment: `[^\/]+` means *any character except `/`* . `/` must be escaped (`\/`). `[^a]` is *any character except `a`* or `[^a-z]` is *any character except `a`, `b`, `c`, ..., `z`* or `[^abc]` is *any character except `a`, `b`, `c`* ...

Comment: Thanks @manolo though I forgot to mention that extension may vary in original URL so i extended your answer to `$reg = "#[^\/]+\..{3,4}\/$#"; `

Comment: @DevUtkarsh Are you sure that works? Check [this out](http://regex101.com/r/kI8dR9)... [or this](http://ideone.com/xGU5xS). I mean, it's replacing the slash at the end.

Comment: @jerry - my target was to append the new element in original URL. It doesn't matters what the appended URL results in. I only had to take care of slash(/) in original URL because I was writing the regex for it .. :)

Comment: @DevUtkarsh That means that your original regex would have worked if you removed `.*` and placed the `*` outside, like this: `[^/]*` instead of this: `[^/.*]` because the latter matches only a single character. PS: You don't need to escape `/` when you use `#` as regex delimiter.

Comment: @Jerry - yeah right :D i was trying since an hour..was not able to realize my mistake. Thanks. Anyways i learned a awesome way for testing regex at [link](http://regex101.com/) Thanks alot man.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done without regular expressions as well, using implode and explode. This should work-

```
$url = "http://www.something.com/folder_path/contacts.php/";
$arr = explode("/",$url);
$new_element = "index.php";
$arr[count($arr) - 2] = $new_element;
echo implode("/",$arr);
// Prints - http://www.something.com/folder_path/index.php/
```

Comment: Thanks . I already did this. But I wanted to do it by regex specifically.